# create a vpn Azure

Tags: azure, vpn, azure-powershell

There is a problem when I enter the respective information in this lines of code. My purpose is to create a vpn

```
$rgName = "<your new resource group name >"
$locName = "<the location of your new resource group>"
$saName = "<storage account name>"
New-AzureRMStorageAccount -Name $saName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Type
Standard_LRS -lOCATION $locName
```

> New-AzureRmStorageAccount : Missing an argument for parameter
>   'SkuName'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String' and try again.
>   At line:4 char:68
>   + ... -AzureRMStorageAccount -Name $saName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Type
>   +                                                                     ~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-AzureRmStorageAccount], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.NewAzureStorageAccountCommand
>
> Standard_LRS : The term 'Standard_LRS' is not recognized as the name
>   of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again. At line:5 char:1
>   + Standard_LRS -lOCATION $locName
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Standard_LRS:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, please try this command with "", like

```
PS C:\>New-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -AccountName "MyStorageAccount" -Location "US West" -Type "Standard_GRS"
```

More information refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.storage/v1.2.0/New-AzureRmStorageAccount?redirectedfrom=msdn).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Does it work now, if it helps, please don't forget to mark it as answer, thanks.